# Java: Editing Values in a String[]

Tags: java

I am a C++/C# developer but I am new to Java. I am trying to implement setters and getters for an array of strings within a basic class, like so:

```
private String[] values = new String[35];

public String get_val(int idx) 
{
    return values[idx];
}

public void set_val(int idx, String val) 
{
    values[idx] = val;
}
```

When I call the `set_val` function, it will update the value of the nth string. After running code such as the following:

```
row.set_val(0, row.get_val(0) + "1");
row.set_val(0, row.get_val(1) + "2");
row.set_val(0, row.get_val(2) + "3");

string foo = row.get_val(0);
```

By the time the `string foo = row.get_val(0);`, the 0th value is back to its original value. Am I missing a concept with arrays and Java? This seems like pretty straight forward code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The posted code should work as expected. Maybe you're doing something else that you haven't posted here (and we can't analyze) or maybe `row.get_val(0)` was `row.get_val(2) + "3"` before running the code.

Comment: Why are you doing your own bounds checking? The Java runtime already does it for you.

Comment: And it does it correctly, which your code doesn't. That last index of an array of length 35 is 34.

Comment: @JBNizet, I had a col_count - 1 and no references to 35 but I quickly swapped it out with 35 to simplify the code for the example. It should say 34.

Comment: @GrahamBorland I had other logic also built in there but stripped it out for the sake of the example. I should have removed all references to it as it is not related to the question

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I just went back and watched the values through the debugger. I set it to {"abc", "def", "ghi"}. It updated it to "abc1", then after the call to the second value, the 0th string became "def". By the time it made it back to the "string foo" line, it was back to "abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine as programmed, but I would heavily consider using the ArrayList structure built into java instead. It's pre-cooked into java, and if you initialize the size,

```
private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(35);
```

you should get the same (if not better runtime performance, and not need to do any bounds checking)

```
private final MAX_SIZE = 35;

public String get_val(int idx)
{
    if(idx<strings.size())
        return strings.get(idx);
    else
        return null;
}

public void set_val(int idx, String val)
{
    if(idx<MAX_SIZE)
        strings.add(val,idx);
    else
        //throw an exception if that's how you really want to do it
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest lists as a matter of flexibility and maintainability rather than performance... also, the `get` method (as the index of an array) both throw an exception if the index is out of range. Still, I don't disagree with the suggestion as long as the OP isn't sticking to arrays on purpose.

Comment: Looking at the API you're correct--it's just one potential answer of many :D

Comment: That's why I said I don't completely disagree ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input! I tried ArrayList but somewhere along the line I got frustrated and decided to reinvent the wheel, I guess, lol. I'll give that a try.